# JBoss and Resteasy: ClassNotFoundException while deserializing java-serialized object

Tags: java, serialization, jboss, resteasy, activiti

Context: we are using Activiti as a process engine and Activiti-Rest as its interface towards our application. As the question is related to REST services returning objects serialized by Java, I did not add this to the title.

Scenario: we have a JBoss Wildfly instance which contains an EAR with a module (lets call it X for reference) that contains a class "ProcessContext". Activiti is running inside this EAR and the ServiceTasks (Java-snippets getting called from the processes to do some work) depend on that class. They use this class to instantiate a process variable and add some data to it.

We have a second deployment (a WAR, currently on the same Wildfly instance but later on a remote server), which accesses Activiti by its REST api and now we need to access the "ProcessContext" data. This WAR also has a dependency on X and its classloader can resolve "ProcessContext" without problems.

Ok, fine. Doing so seemed simple. Call:

```
GET history/historic-process-instances/{processInstanceId}/variables/{variableName}/data
```

This returns a response with MediaType "application/x-java-serialized-object" and inspecting it with the debugger seemed fine. But when I tried to deserialize the object I got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xxx.commons.metadata.ProcessMetadata from [Module "org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs:main" from local module loader @103f852 (finder: local module finder @587c290d (roots: /opt/wildfly/modules,/opt/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base))]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:626) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.SerializableProvider.readFrom(SerializableProvider.java:76) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
... 131 more
```

Wondering about it I found that the Classloader that is used to deserialize the object if the Module-Classloader of the **Resteasy module** instead my local (module) classloader.

One solution would probably be to write a module that contains "ProcessContext" and make it globally known in JBoss but that is some infrastructure-decission that was denied by the project lead.

Shouldn't Resteasy rather use the classloader of the caller instead its module classloader? The caller knows its required classes and if I could get hands on the responses internal input stream I could deserialize it myself without any problems. I realy wonder if this a bug or a feature.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, finally I found a solution by writing an own provider and registering it with the Resteasy client programmatically. I also tried doing this by web.xml but that did not work as I will explain.

For others who have a similr problem here my solution. The message body provider:

```
@Provider
@Consumes("application/x-java-serialized-object")
public class ActivitiObjectMessageBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader<ProcessMetadata> {

@Override
public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return (type == ProcessMetadata.class && "application/x-java-serialized-object".equals(mediaType.toString()));
}

@Override
public ProcessMetadata readFrom(Class<ProcessMetadata> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(entityStream);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
    try {
        return ProcessMetadata.class.cast(ois.readObject());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(e);
    }
}
```

}

I know, I probably do not need the whole expression in the isReadable due to the annotation but well...

The programmatical registration looks like this:

```
ResteasyProviderFactory factory = new ResteasyProviderFactory();
factory.register(new ActivitiObjectMessageBodyReader());
Configuration configuration = new ClientConfiguration(factory);
```

Now I can use the configuration like this:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(configuration);
```

And wow, the Java object variable is retrieved over REST.

----- You can stop reading here unless you want to know about what I think are the reasons of the problem -----

The problem is related to the loading of provider factories inside resteasy. I debugged into it and saw it swapping the providers against the configured providers like this:

```
Providers current = ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(Providers.class);
ResteasyProviderFactory.pushContext(Providers.class, configuration);
```

When using web.xml or RegisterBuiltin.register(factory) to register my provider globally, the provider can be found in current after the above calls but current is not used for deserialization. Instead the configuration is used and this has a chain of parent factories that result in the factory initialized within the Resteasy module, which does not contain my provider and cannot find my class, due to its own classloader.
And yes, I have e.g. resteasy.scan enabled in web.xml but it does not help.

When providing the factory to the client, it injects it into the response constructor and now the provider is available at serialization time, using the classloader of my own module (as it is registered as a bean), which results in the desired deserialized object.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste original Jboss SerializableProvider into your application and declare it in web.xml

https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/SerializableProvider.java

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```